std::allocate_shared: get access to allocated memory from construct
I've made a simple allocator to be used with std::allocate_shared, see the following example:
#include <memory>
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t ceil_to_multiple(std::size_t number, std::size_t multiple)
{
    return number + multiple - 1 - (number + multiple - 1) % multiple;
}

template <typename T>
struct shared_ptr_storage
{
    constexpr static std::size_t align = std::max(alignof(void*), alignof(T));
    constexpr static std::size_t size = ceil_to_multiple(sizeof(T), align) + 32;
    std::array<std::byte, size> buffer;
};

template <class T>
struct shared_allocator;

template <class T, class U>
struct shared_allocator_impl
{
    using value_type = U;

    shared_allocator_impl() = delete;
    shared_allocator_impl(const shared_allocator<T>&) {}

    static_assert(sizeof(U) <= shared_ptr_storage<T>::size);

    constexpr std::size_t max_size() const noexcept { return 1; }

    value_type* allocate(std::size_t) {
        return reinterpret_cast<value_type*>(new shared_ptr_storage<T>{});
    }

    void deallocate(value_type* p, std::size_t) {
        delete reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr_storage<T>*>(p);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct shared_allocator {
    using value_type = T;

    shared_allocator() = default;

    constexpr std::size_t max_size() const noexcept { return 1; }

    template <typename... arguments>
    void construct(value_type* p, arguments&&... parameters)
    {
        std::construct_at(p, std::forward<arguments>(parameters)...);
    }

    void destroy(value_type* p)
    {
        p->~value_type();
    }

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind{
        using other = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>, shared_allocator<T>, shared_allocator_impl<T, U>>;
    };
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const shared_allocator<T>&, const shared_allocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const shared_allocator<T>&, const shared_allocator<U>&) { return false; }

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const shared_allocator<T>&, const shared_allocator_impl<T, U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const shared_allocator<T>&, const shared_allocator_impl<T, U>&) { return false; }

int main()
{
    shared_allocator<int> allocator;
    auto i = std::allocate_shared<int>(allocator, 10);
    auto j = std::allocate_shared<int>(allocator, 20);
}

I want to be able to get at the full shared_ptr_storage struct from construct() and destroy(), but since it's not standardized what type is allocated underneath, I cannot find a reliable way to do it cross platform.
I need it so that I can add extra properties to shared_ptr_storage and then access them later in construct().

How about storing them counting backwards from p?

I don't understand what you're trying to say here. I can keep all allocations in a list, then search for a p somewhere inside one of the allocations. But that feels like doing a lot of unnecessary work.

Sorry, that's not what I meant.  I'm assuming that you're allocating more space than is actually needed for T to make rook for some housekeeping information (or whatever).  Can you store this information 'right justified' (i.e. just behind p), rather than 'left justified' (i.e. relative to the start of the block).

@catnip The problem is that what std::allocate_shared<int> asks the allocator to allocate memory for is not int, but something like struct Internal { ControlBlock cb; int obj; };. The exact definition is an internal implementation detail. Then consruct gets an int* pointer that points somewhere into the middle of Internal - there's no way of knowing how far Internal goes in either direction from that pointer. So allocate could stash additional data before or after Internal, but construct wouldn't know where to look for that data.
